# Group data in one column based on conditions in multiple columns - dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

This is an extension of another question that I have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58153206/group-data-in-one-column-based-on-a-string-value-in-another-column-using-dplyr). I have the below data for a group of students which specifies the tasks assigned to each of them during different days of their school term.

```
df <- data.frame(
    Student = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
    `Day of School` = c("Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Field Trip", "Field Trip", "Field Trip", "Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 3", "Day 3", "Day 4", "Day 4", "Day 4", "Field Trip", "Field Trip", "Field Trip", "Field Trip", "Field Trip", "Day 5", "Day 5", "Day 5"),
    Task = c("Homework", "Classwork", "Homework", "Classwork", "Homework", "Classwork", "Poster", "Poster", "Poster", "Homework", "Classwork", "Homework", "Classwork", "Homework", "Classwork", "Poster", "Poster", "Poster", "Homework", "Classwork", "Homework", "Classwork", "Homework", "Classwork","Poster", "Poster"),
    Status = c("Completed", "Completed", "Completed", "Completed", "Completed", "Completed", "Completed", "Pending", "Not performed", "Completed", "Pending", "Completed", "Completed", "Pending", "Not performed", "Completed", "Pending", "Not performed", "Completed", "Completed", "Completed","Completed", "Completed", "Completed", "Completed", "Completed"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to summarize this table as below

[image]

Where the **No. of students completed** should be counted, if a student has status of all tasks for a particular day of school as **Completed**. Could anyone guide me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Day.of.School, Student) %>%
 summarise(n = all(Status == "Completed")) %>%
 group_by(Day.of.School) %>%
 summarise(n = sum(n))

  Day.of.School     n
  <chr>         <int>
1 Day 1             1
2 Day 2             2
3 Day 3             0
4 Day 4             0
5 Day 5             1
6 Field Trip        1
```

Comment: Nice and tidy. Thank you!